# How Do you make a delay in python without stoping the whole program

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a game for a presentation and I cannot seem to understand how to make a delay in Python.

For example, whenever I press the D key, my character not only moves but also changes pictures so it looks like it's running.

I have the movement part down, I just need to slow down the changing of the sprite so that it doesn't look like he's running a million miles per hour. I have set the FPS.

Comment: You're going to need two threads.

Comment: This question isn't very clear. Are you using pygame, or making a cli game using curses?

Comment: Multithreading is the way to go but you might be able to hack it by just adding `time.sleep(0.01)` between each of your "frames". It will slow down all your program logic but that may be acceptable for simple cases.

Answer (score 0):

The command `turtle.down()` will work, I guess

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using multithreading, you could say

```
timer = pygame.USEREVENT + 1;
pygame.time.set_timer(timer, RUN_DELAY_IN_MILLISECONDS)
```

when your character starts to run,

```
if event.type == timer:
   [change sprite image]
```

in your event loop, and `pygame.time.set_timer(timer, 0)` when your character stops running

In this case, pygame's event system will manage the timing

Comment: ok i used this code and understand how it works but how would i do it with multiple images

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "how would i do it with multiple images"

Comment: how would i say first make a list of images and then every time the loop goes by it draws the next image in that list. because what i see is that every time the loop restarts it draws the same image

Comment: I did not put any image drawing code in my example. That code would go in the place where i say [change sprite image]. You seem to be asking a seperate question, which you should [ask seperately](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).